# Inject a CSS class into HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to use CSS classes to prevent repeating color codes (per example) on the highchart that I'm working on right now. The idea is that these CSS classes will be used here but considering that not all charts that come afterwards are going to be the same as this one, I don't want to manipulate the style of all of them.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

The javascript, changing the background of it to the colour on the CSS class

```
$('#container').highcharts({
 chart: {
 type: 'column', 
 backgroundColor: '.bc'
},...
```

The css:

```
.bc{
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If not, would there be a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

backgroundColor:color

the background color can get any color like

> backgroundColor: '#42431D'

the defaults value is #FFFFFF (white)

the other option is gradient -

> ```
> backgroundColor: {
>             linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
>             stops: [
>                 [0, 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'],
>                 [1, 'rgb(0, 0, 0)']
>                 ..........
>             ]
> ```

I do not think there are other options in this case

Comment: But won't this change the background of all the charts that might be used after this one? Plus, I wanted to put it in the css of a page and then use it on the javascript, that's what I'm asking if it's possible...

Comment: Going to look into Themes (which is what I think you're talking about). Thanks for the tip regardless!

Comment: Indeed, check themes - that's how you can set options for multiple chart. For now Highcharts aren't based on CSS classes (well, partially is, but it's better to use JS to change options).

Comment: you talk about the background color. if you want to change the column color - yes like pawel says look at themes.

if you want something simple and more flexible you can use d3. or c3 will be more simple to use.   http://c3js.org/

Comment: For now I'm using themes, I'm not sure if it'll be useful for what I'm trying to do in the longer run but for now it works. Thanks and I'll keep the d3/c3 in mind. Thanks for the help.